# How to get value in loop after concatenating two string

Tags: jsp, jstl

Say i have variables with name SOH_EVENT_1,SOH_EVENT_2,.....,SOH_EVENT_21.

i am trying to get value of these variables within loop..something like this-

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="21" varStatus="loopCount">

<C:out value="${SOH_EVENT_loopCount.count}" />

</c:forEach>
```

But i am not able to get the exact value of these variables.When i put this line of code for each variable i am able to get the values but not in side loop after concatenating string with count.

```
<C:out value="${SOH_EVENT_1}" />
<C:out value="${SOH_EVENT_2}" />
...
....
<C:out value="${SOH_EVENT_21}" />
```

How can i get the value inside loop.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Are those just plain variables or attributes present in some scope such as request / session / pageContext?

Comment: i have created these variable on jsp...could add scope if required..

Answer (score 0):

If you put those variables in some scope, say request, it becomes easier:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="21" varStatus="loopCount">
    <c:set var="key" value="SOH_EVENT_${loopCount.index}"/>
    <C:out value="${request[key]}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i am getting error Property 'SOH_EVENT_1' not found on type com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest...and i have added this line of code <c:set var="SOH_EVENT_1" value="vivek" scope="request" />

Comment: Try using `pageContext` or `page` instead of `request`.

Comment: Property 'SOH_EVENT_1' not found on type java.lang.String for page scope

Comment: Try changing that c:out to `${pageScope[key]}` or `${requestScope[key]}` or `${sessionScope[key]}` or `${applicationScope[key]}`